# Corona net::ERR_CACHE_MISS comes when loading an external url in Corona

Tags: web, view, coronasdk

I am using Corona to make an app. I have implemented following code to open a website/a page inside my app view instead of browser:

```
    function openLink(event)
    if(event.phase == "ended")then
        print("btn clicked")

        local webView = native.newWebView( display.contentCenterX, display.contentCenterY, 320, 480 )
        webView:request( "http://www.coronalabs.com/" )

        local text1 = display.newText("",100,100,native.systemFontBold,20)
        text1.text = "native should come"
    end
end

btn:addEventListener("touch", openLink)
```

Its giving me following error on device when button is tapped:

```
net::ERR_CACHE_MISS
```

Please help me out with this. Also, I have few questions regarding feasibility of this function.

- Can I access full interactivity of website inside app view? i.e. scroll through pages, open other pages, navigate to other elements of website etc.
- If I can't access complete website with ease, is there any possibility that I can open multiple pages one after another of same website on click of various buttons created by me inside app?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The ERR_CACHE_MISS error comes from Chrome. To avoid it, check the following:

1. Make sure you can get to the URL from a browser on the mobile
   device to ensure the issue isn't with your Internet connection.
2. Make sure that your build.settings file in your Corona app allows for Internet
   permissions. For Android, this means including the following in build.settings:

   -- Android permissions
   androidPermissions = {
       "android.permission.INTERNET",
   },